# Alter Table Drop Column error - VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying top drop a column called "Cost centre" in a table called "sheet1". I have written the following statement that works for columns with one word:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Alter Table Sheet1 Drop Column Cost centre;"
```

However with this one it only tries to drop a column called "Cost" which does not exist. I have tried using 'Cost centre'; ect but have had no luck with it.

I am sure there is a simple solution for this, however I have been unable to find it.

Comment: As a tip, when I can't remember the SQL, I just create an Access Query, open the SQL View and copy + paste the SQL into my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the column name in brackets, like `[Cost centre]`.

Comment: If it has a space like "Cost centre" does. Otherwise, it is fine without.